# Install libpng version 1.6 for Ubuntu 19?

Tags: networking, glibc

How to install `libpng` for Ubuntu 19 so that I would be able to open Packet Tracer 7.2.1?

Comment: There is not Ubuntu 19 (Ubuntu releases are generally *yy.mm* in format, Ubuntu Core & specialist releases do use *yy* having only a single release on even years - but not odd years).  Maybe you need `libpng-dev` , ie. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libpng&searchon=names  (you didn't specify your exact release, but they have ver 1.6.x)

Answer (score 2):

If your question is only about how to install `libpng16`, open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt install libpng16-16
```

This should work for both Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco) and 19.10 (Eoan), since both versions contain the `libpng16-16` package in their [repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libpng16&searchon=names).

Answer (score 0):

*Steps done with Ubuntu 18.04*

1. Search `libpng` packages:

   ```
   apt-cache search libpng
   ```

   Got this result:

   ```
   libpng-dev - PNG library - development (version 1.6)
   libpng-tools - PNG library - tools (version 1.6)
   libpng16-16 - PNG library - runtime (version 1.6)
   fp-units-gfx - Free Pascal - graphics-library units dependency package
   fp-units-gfx-3.0.4 - Free Pascal - graphics-library units
   libpnglite0 - lightweight C library for loading and writing PNG images
   pngquant - Utilitaire d'optimisation d'images PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
   libpng++-dev - C++ interface to the PNG (Portable Network Graphics) library
   libpng-sixlegs-java - Sixlegs Java PNG Decoder
   libpng-sixlegs-java-doc - Documentation for Sixlegs Java PNG Decoder
   libpnglite-dev - lightweight C library for loading and writing PNG images
   ruby-oily-png - native mixin to speed up ChunkyPNG
   tkpng - PNG photo image support to Tcl/Tk
   ```
2. Install adequate package:

   ```
   sudo apt install libpng16-16
   ```
3. Install feature package (optionnal):

   ```
   sudo apt install libpng-tools
   ```

`libpng-tools` could be useful, but I don't think it must be install to run Packet Tracer (but probably compulsory for advanced features

NB: `-cache` option gives you easily package names

Comment: This is important information